# Who divided/rearranged the brāhmaṇas, āraṇyakas and upaniṣads?

Tags: vedas, history, vyasa, brahmanas, aranyaka

According to [SB 12.6.50](https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish#page/n2185/mode/2up) it appears Vyāsa (Kṛṣṇa Dvaipāyana) only rearranged the Vedic mantras into four parts:

> 50. Just as (out of a heap of mixed up) 
>   precious stones of the same kind are assorted and kept in 
>   separate heaps, he (Vyāsa) selected and **classified the Vedic 
>   Mantras** as belonging to the category of the Ṛg, Atharvan, 
>   Yajus, and Sāman and **thus compiled four *Saṃhitās*** or collections out of those (formerly mixed up) *Mantras*.

So who classified the various brāhmaṇas, āraṇyakas and upaniṣads into the four Vedic branches? Was it Vyāsa's disciples?

Comment: Veda Vyasa is so called because he divided the Vedas .. and he divided only the Samhita portions .. that means only the Samhita portions are the Vedas ..